# Get data from helper in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a trouble with CodeIgniter.
I would like to get (recoup) data from a helper that I call in a view.
I will explain with the code

Here's my view :

```
// CALL THE FUNCTION FROM THE HELPER
    <?php recup_email(); ?>

// DATA RECOUP FROM THE HELPER
    <?php foreach($em as $e): ?>
       <?php echo $e->email_membre; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

As you can see, I call the function and just after I would like to use data that I had recoup.

Here's my helper :

```
function recup_email()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('unite_model');

    $data['em'] = $CI->unite_model->email_membre_model();        
}
```

But I don't know how to recoup data without using

```
    $layout_network['contenu'] = $this->load->view('list_vote_friend', $data, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('layout_network',$layout_network);
```

because the view is already loaded.

I hope you understand, sorry for my bad english.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example you have given, why not just return the data from the helper function?

```
function recup_email()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('unite_model');

    $membres = $CI->unite_model->email_membre_model();  
    return $membres;      
}
```

So that is you view;

```
// CALL THE FUNCTION FROM THE HELPER
    <?php $em = recup_email(); ?>

// DATA RECOUP FROM THE HELPER
    <?php foreach($em as $e): ?>
       <?php echo $e->email_membre; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Waaa, I am sorry it's true, what a awesome idea !! Thank you a lot.